# Is UIBezierPath available for iphone 4.0 onwards?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

is iphone sdk 4.0 supports UIBezierPath since in documentation they told its available above 3.2 but they didnt told it is available in iphone or it just only for ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIBezierPath` is available in iOS 4.0+. In fact, it was [revised](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009276-CH99-SW1) and methods were added in iOS 4.0.